# Python Assign List of Entry to Variable

Tags: python, list, variables, variable-assignment

In its current state I have created two lists, `NameValues` and `AgeValues` which contain the values written into a series of generated entry boxes when a button is clicked. I now need to insert them into a sqlite table. Before I can do the query however I am having problems assigning all the values to the variables `Name` and `Age`.

My problem is that if there are 2 entry boxes created for each variable and the values are submitted the program will only get the values in the last set of entry boxes, retrieving only half the data.

This is the code to fetch the data:

```
  NameValues = []
  AgeValues = []

def Insert(self):

    for i in range(len(self.NameValues)):
        Name = (self.NameValues[i].get())

    for i in range(len(self.AgeValues)):
       Age = (self.AgeValues[i].get())

    Code = self.MemberCode.get()

    print (Age)
```

I am printing the age as a test to see what values are stored in the variables and only the last value is being entered.

Comment: The print statement for age is out of indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `Name & Age` as a list. I have used `list comprehension` to assign all value to `Name` and `Age` list.

**Ex:**

```
NameValues = []
AgeValues = []

def Insert(self):


    Name = [self.NameValues[i].get() for i in range(len(self.NameValues))]
    Age =[self.AgeValues[i].get() for i in range(len(self.AgeValues))]
    Code = self.MemberCode.get()

    print (Age)
```

Comment: Thanks I made the modifications to the code and it printed multiple values.